# Setting html text to Description of VCALENDAR

Tags: html, outlook

I want to set the html text in the description of the vcalendar.
How to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately Outlook doesn't support HTML in vCalendar/ICS event descriptions.

When using Outlook, rich text format can be used in descriptions. However when you try to export it, the formatting gets dropped and a hard coded wrapper (customized on the fly by the application logic) is added to fix the text encoding. The encoding can be changed through Outlook settings, oh thanks god ! =P